# What is the <sparkle:ReleaseNotesLink> actually for?

Tags: xml, rss, sparkle

I am using Sparkle framework for application updates, and I am wondering what url in the `<sparkle:ReleaseNotesLink>` tag is actually used for?

According to the documentation, "You can provide additional release notes for localization purposes."
https://github.com/andymatuschak/Sparkle/wiki/publishing-an-update#localization

```
<sparkle:releaseNotesLink>http://you.com/app/2.0.html</sparkle:releaseNotesLink>
<sparkle:releaseNotesLink xml:lang="de">http://you.com/app/2.0_German.html</sparkle:releaseNotesLink>
```

I understand adding language codes to the tag for different languages. What I don't understand is how the link is utilized or accessed? A link to a "Release Notes" page does not show in the rss feed. So, if only using a single language, does the tag have a purpose?

I thought it might add a link to the description shown when there is an update that said "Complete Change log here" or something similar, but it does not. It also does not show a "link" when viewing the xml file in a web browser, so I am confused as to the tags purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sparkle RSS definition is an extension to the standard RSS definition.  The sparkle-specific items are only used by the Sparkle framework, in order to properly determine versions, or display release notes when prompting a user for a new update.  A web browser (expecting a run-of-the-mill RSS feed, sans Sparkle extensions) won't show all the magic goo that the Sparkle framework can take advantage of when invoked within your app.

The [sample test appcast](http://sparkle-project.org/files/sparkletestcast.xml) provided by the Sparkle project has two sparkle-specific item fields defined in the feed:

1. wraps a URL that contains release notes to be displayed in the popup window proposing a new release to users.
2. sparkle:version, sparkle:shortVersionString, and sparkle:dsaSignature are three Sparkle-specific attributes to the "enclosure" tag, which allow the Sparkle framework to propose the newest version, display a meaningful user-facing version, and ensure that the user's download was completed successfully and safely.  If the signature value isn't correct, your users will get a message explaining that (IIRC) "The file appears corrupted/damaged".

Generally, these are easily tested by simply performing an update using Sparkle on another computer (aside from your usual dev machine), as both versions and signature would be checked and/or displayed during a normal update procedure.  This, combined with the output inspection you describe (within a web browser) should be sufficient to ensure that your appcast is well-formed.

The best canonical definition I could find for the subtleties of the Sparkle extensions is in the location you pointed to in your question:
https://github.com/sparkle-project/Sparkle/wiki/publishing-an-update